# Getting Error In Doinbackground in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

below is my code help me in removing this error trying to build a weather app help me friends so that I can show this app as my minor project.no error is showing in android studio but when I press my button it shows the below code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;``
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jso`enter code here`n.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText cityName;
TextView resultTextView;

public void findWeather(View view){

Log.i("cityName",cityName.getText().toString());

InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService    (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cityName.getWindowToken(),0);

    try {
        String encodedCityName = URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

     DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
     task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could Not Find Weather",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }



}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cityName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);


}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could Not Find Weather",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {

            String message = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
           String weatherInfo= jsonObject.getString("weather");
            Log.i("Weather Content",weatherInfo);
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
           for (int i = 0; i < arr.length();i++) {

               JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
               String main = "";
               String description = "";
               main = jsonPart.getString("main");

               description = jsonPart.getString("description");

               if (main != "" && description != ""){

                message += main + "; " + description + "\r\n";
               }
           }

            if (message != ""){

                resultTextView.setText(message);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could Not Find Weather",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could Not Find Weather",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }


    }


}
```

}

below is error help me friends

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                 at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                 at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
                                                 at com.example.shaarif.test3.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                 at com.example.shaarif.test3.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Your are accessing UI thread from background thread(non UI thread)

Comment: Ahamed..I posted all the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can not toast your message from doInBackground() method.

try to remove this line, and then try.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could Not Find Weather",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

and If you must show message from doInBackground() method try to use handler or thread.

But it is a bad practice to perform UI transitions from doInBackground() try to do it from onPostExecute() method.

Comment: Still Not Working.